# xPath retrieve list attributes

Tags: list, xpath, get, attributes

There is xml document:

```
<home>
 <page name="Home"></page>
 <page name="Photos"></page>
 <page name="News"></page>
 <page name="About Us"></page>
</home>
```

How to retrieve values of all name 
attributes using xPath to create list of link.

Desirable not to use for-each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath `/home/page/@name` will return all `name` attributes from the `page` element.

For example usage in a XSLT, with template matching:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xa;'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@name">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

A set containing all name attributes can be obtained with this absolute expression:

```xml
/home/page/@name
```

or with this descendant axis expression:

```xml
//page/@name
```